# I want to find the highest price since entry in pine script?

Tags: automation, pine-script, trading, highest

I want to find the highest price and exit when current price is lower than highest price. The code to find the highest price is copied from here. how can I make a simpler code that finds highest price since entry? I also want to close the deal if current price is lower than a specific price. Please help me.

```
// SETTING //
length1=input(1)
length3=input(3)
length7=input(7)
length20=input(20)
length60=input(60)
length120=input(120)
ma1= sma(close,length1)
ma3= sma(close,length3)
ma7= sma(close,length7)
ma20=sma(close,length20)
ma60=sma(close,length60)
ma120=sma(close,length120)
rsi=rsi(close,14)
// BUYING VOLUME AND SELLING VOLUME //
BV = iff( (high==low), 0, volume*(close-low)/(high-low))
SV = iff( (high==low), 0, volume*(high-close)/(high-low))
vol = iff(volume > 0, volume, 1)
dailyLength = input(title = "Daily MA length", type = input.integer, defval = 50, minval = 1, maxval = 100)
weeklyLength = input(title = "Weekly MA length", type = input.integer, defval = 10, minval = 1, maxval = 100)
//-----------------------------------------------------------
Davgvol = sma(volume, dailyLength)
Wavgvol = sma(volume, weeklyLength)
//-----------------------------------------------------------
length = input(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
mult2= input(1.5, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="exp")
mult3= input(1.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="exp1")
basis = sma(src, length)
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
dev2= mult2 * stdev(src, length)
Supper= basis + dev2
Slower= basis - dev2
dev3= mult3 * stdev(src, length)
upper1= basis + dev3
lower1= basis - dev3
offset = input(0, "Offset", type = input.integer, minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))
//----------------------------------------------------
exit=(close-strategy.position_avg_price / strategy.position_avg_price*100)
bull=(low>upper and BV>SV and BV>Davgvol)
bux =(close<Supper and close>Slower and volume<Wavgvol)
bear=(close<Slower and close<lower and SV>BV and SV>Wavgvol)
hi=highest(exit,10)


// - INPUTS
ShowPivots = input(true, title="Show Pivot Points")
ShowHHLL = input(true, title="Show HH,LL,LH,HL markers on Pivots Points")
left = input(5, minval=1, title="Pivot Length Left Hand Side")
right = input(5, minval=1, title="Pivot Length Right Hand Side")
ShowSRLevels = input(true, title="Show S/R Level Extensions")
maxLvlLen = input(0, minval=0, title="Maximum S/R Level Extension Length (0 = Max)")
ShowChannel = input(false, title="Show Levels as a Fractal Chaos Channel")
//
ShowFB = input(true, title="Show Fractal Break Alert Arrows")


// Determine pivots
pvtLenL = left
pvtLenR = right

// Get High and Low Pivot Points
pvthi_ = pivothigh(high, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)
pvtlo_ = pivotlow(low, pvtLenL, pvtLenR)

// Force Pivot completion before plotting.
pvthi = pvthi_
pvtlo = pvtlo_

//  ||-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------||
//  ||---   Higher Highs, Lower Highs, Higher Lows, Lower Lows  -------------------------------------------||
valuewhen_1 = valuewhen(pvthi, high[pvtLenR], 1)
valuewhen_2 = valuewhen(pvthi, high[pvtLenR], 0)
higherhigh = na(pvthi) ? na : valuewhen_1 < valuewhen_2 ? pvthi : na
valuewhen_3 = valuewhen(pvthi, high[pvtLenR], 1)
valuewhen_4 = valuewhen(pvthi, high[pvtLenR], 0)
lowerhigh = na(pvthi) ? na : valuewhen_3 > valuewhen_4 ? pvthi : na
valuewhen_5 = valuewhen(pvtlo, low[pvtLenR], 1)
valuewhen_6 = valuewhen(pvtlo, low[pvtLenR ], 0)
higherlow = na(pvtlo) ? na : valuewhen_5 < valuewhen_6 ? pvtlo : na
valuewhen_7 = valuewhen(pvtlo, low[pvtLenR], 1)
valuewhen_8 = valuewhen(pvtlo, low[pvtLenR ], 0)
lowerlow = na(pvtlo) ? na : valuewhen_7 > valuewhen_8 ? pvtlo : na


// If selected Display the HH/LL above/below candle.
plotshape(ShowHHLL ? higherhigh : na, title='HH', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green,50), text="HH", offset=-pvtLenR)
plotshape(ShowHHLL ? higherlow : na, title='HL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green,50), text="HL", offset=-pvtLenR)
plotshape(ShowHHLL ? lowerhigh : na, title='LH', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red,50), text="LH", offset=-pvtLenR)
plotshape(ShowHHLL ? lowerlow : na, title='LL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red,50), text="LL", offset=-pvtLenR)


plot(ShowPivots and not ShowHHLL ? pvthi : na, title='High Pivot', style=plot.style_circles, join=false, color=color.green, offset=-pvtLenR, linewidth=3)
plot(ShowPivots and not ShowHHLL ? pvtlo : na, title='Low Pivot', style=plot.style_circles, join=false, color=color.red, offset=-pvtLenR, linewidth=3)

//Count How many candles for current Pivot Level, If new reset.
counthi = 0
countlo = 0
counthi := na(pvthi) ? nz(counthi[1]) + 1 : 0
countlo := na(pvtlo) ? nz(countlo[1]) + 1 : 0

pvthis = 0.0
pvtlos = 0.0
pvthis := na(pvthi) ? pvthis[1] : high[pvtLenR]
pvtlos := na(pvtlo) ? pvtlos[1] : low[pvtLenR]

hipc = pvthis != pvthis[1] ? na : color.new(color.red,50)
lopc = pvtlos != pvtlos[1] ? na : color.new(color.green,50)

// Show Levels if Selected
plot(ShowSRLevels and not ShowChannel and (maxLvlLen == 0 or counthi < maxLvlLen) ? pvthis : na, color=hipc, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLenR , title="Top Levels",style=plot.style_circles)
plot(ShowSRLevels and not ShowChannel and (maxLvlLen == 0 or countlo < maxLvlLen) ? pvtlos : na, color=lopc, linewidth=1, offset=-pvtLenR , title="Bottom Levels",style=plot.style_circles)

// Show Levels as a Fractal Chaos Channel
plot(ShowSRLevels and ShowChannel ? pvthis : na, color=color.green, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_stepline, offset=0, title="Top Chaos Channel", trackprice=false)
plot(ShowSRLevels and ShowChannel ? pvtlos : na, color=color.red, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_stepline, offset=0, title="Bottom Chaos Channel", trackprice=false)

// //
float fixedHH = fixnan(higherhigh)

// add offset = -pvtLenR to move the plot to the left and match the HH points.
plot(fixedHH)

bool lowerThanHH = close < fixedHH
float closeHHDiff = abs(fixedHH - close)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high + 3*tr, tostring(closeHHDiff), xloc.bar_index, color = color.gray, style = label.style_label_down)

// STRATEGY LONG //
if (bull and close>ma3 and ma20>ma60)
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long,1)
    
if (higherhigh*0.80==close)`enter code here`
    strategy.close("Long",1)
```

Comment: thanks for helping me it`s solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imInATrade = strategy.position size != 0

highestPriceAfterEntry = valuewhen(imInATrade, high, 0)
```

The code above finds the highest price after entry or when you're in a trade.